# How can I start a process on the start of a Seam application

Tags: java, seam

I tried annotating the class with the scopetype APPLICATION and a method with the @Create, @Beg, but this doesn't seem to work.

What I want is to start an infinite loop right when the application starts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want a method to be executed right after initialization you can use the folowing annotation:

```
@Observer("org.jboss.seam.postInitialization")
```

Comment: don't forget to add @Name("chooseOneName") to your class

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate your class with the [@Startup](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.0.GA/api/org/jboss/seam/annotations/Startup.html) annotation.